# In a UITabBarController, how do I find out which UIViewController in my Tab Bar presented the current UIViewController in Swift 2.x

Tags: ios, swift

I have a `UITabBarController` with `3 Tabs`.

1. Is a `MainViewController`
2. Is a `SummaryViewController`
3. Is a `MenuViewController`

The `SummaryViewController` can either be presented from just the `Tabs` on the bottom bar or it can also be presented from a **menu button** in the `MenuViewController`. When called from the `MenuViewController`'s button all I am doing is calling:

```
tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 2
```

Here’s my issue, I have a **CLOSE** button available in the `SummaryViewController` to go back to the `UIViewController` which presented the said view. That is the effect I would like to create.

In other words, if the user clicks on the `Tab Bar options at the bottom` of the view to get to the `Summary View Controller` and then clicks the `CLOSE` button available in the `Summary View Controller` I would like to send the user back to the `Main View Controller` using `selectedIndex = 1`.

However, if the user clicks on the **menu button** available in the `MenuViewController` to get to the `Summary View Controller` and then clicks the `CLOSE` button I would like to send the user back to the `MenuViewController`.

Thus, how can I find out which `UIViewController` in my `UITabBarController` called the `SummaryViewController` so I can switch to the corresponding `UIViewController` once they click **CLOSE**. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

How about you use `NSUserDefaults`, create a custom Subclass of the `UITabBarController`, or just simply present a new `UIViewController` instance instead of switching tabs to get your desired output?

There are many ways to tackle this problem you're having.

**NSUserDefaults**: Before switching tabs save the current tabBarController's selectedIndex

For example:

```
let key = "SomeTabBarControllerSelectedIndexKey"
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

defaults.setInteger(tabBarController!.selectedIndex, forKey: key)
// then set the new index
tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 2 // this is the new index assuming the previous index was 0 or 1

// then when **CLOSE** is clicked you just set the tabBarController's index to the one you set in the UserDefaults
if let savedIndex = defaults.integerForKey(key) {
    tabBarController?.selectedIndex = savedIndex
}
```

**UITabBarController Subclass**: Create a subclass then use as you will

```
// first we create the new class
class SomeTabBarController: UITabBarController {
    var previousIndex = 0

}
```

In your Storyboard/XIB subclass the UITabBarController to SomeTabBarController

[image]

```
(tabBarController as! SomeTabBarController).previousIndex = tabBarController!.selectedIndex
// then set the new index
tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 2 // this is the new index assuming the previous index was 0 or 1

// then when **CLOSE** is clicked you just set the tabBarController's index to the one you set in the the class
tabBarController?.selectedIndex = (tabBarController as! SomeTabBarController).previousIndex
```

**presentViewController**: Create a new instance of the ViewController you want to present all the time

```
self.presentViewController(SomeViewController())

// when you click the close button inside `SomeViewController` just call
dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
```